# Magento 2 Import - General system exception

Tags: magento2, customer, import, csv, data

I try to import `customer data` into `Magento2` which got exported from a `Magento2` store, but something wont work...

Since its a 1:1 Magento export, the import should be perfectly fine or am I wrong about this ?

Once i check within Magento if the import-file is valid it tells me it is valid but after the import statup i get the "**General system exception happened**" and the import stops as shown in the image below:

[image: Magento 2.1.3 valid import error]

So, **how to fix this issue ?**

**What do i do wrong ?**

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Could you show us (a part of) the csv file you are uploading?

Comment: Thats simple, once your fill up a magento 2 store with a few customers just export them and try to import that into a new store. But i found the error already, I was missing a storeview on the "import-store". Once i've added that it worked fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Problem solved:**

• Missing storeview

After adding the missing storeview the import worked fine.

Comment: I have same error but didn't get any solution :( ..Please help me!

Answer (score 1):

Check your sheet once again. In my case, description had heavy html structure and also had some French words (ex: Rice Entrée). Some of the UTF encoding caused the problem. I just skipped those kind of records and did import. Afterwards, Magento didn't throw any error and imported successfully.